# while loop not letting me enter the text from label

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop

I am trying to break loop if user input word character are same as random generated word character. In case any char of word isn't matching with random generated word character, then it should display unmatched in that label and skip it and check the rest; then lets user try again to guess the right word with same condition maximum 6 times. If limit is reached in last try loop break out.

I tried to break loop, but its not letting me input from label and just keep the previous entry from user and matches it again and again. Displayed counter as 6 rest it working well on displaying matched and unmatched character.

here is my java code

```java
try {
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("E:\\WordyGame\\src\\wordygame\\targetWords.txt"));
  String line = reader.readLine();
  List<String> words = new ArrayList<String> ();
  while (line != null) {
    String[] wordsLine = line.split(" ");
    for (String word: wordsLine) {
        words.add(word);
    }
    line = reader.readLine();

  }

  Random rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
  //getting random word from txt file
  String randomWord = words.get(rand.nextInt(words.size()));
  System.out.println("random word is : " + randomWord);
  String check_word = randomWord.trim().toLowerCase().toString();

  //getting user input from textfield

  //tp count limited attempts
  int count = 0;
  while (count<6) {
    String take_word = type_word.getText().toLowerCase().toString();
    System.out.println("user inpur is " + take_word);
    //dividing word into char and then each char to strings
    //user input word 
    char first = take_word.charAt(0);
    String first1 = String.valueOf(first);
    char second = take_word.charAt(1);
    String second1 = String.valueOf(second);
    char third = take_word.charAt(2);
    String third1 = String.valueOf(third);
    char fourth = take_word.charAt(3);
    String fourth1 = String.valueOf(fourth);
    char fifth = take_word.charAt(4);
    String fifth1 = String.valueOf(fifth);

    //random word from file

    char first2 = check_word.charAt(0);
    String first22 = String.valueOf(first2);
    char second2 = check_word.charAt(1);
    String second22 = String.valueOf(second2);
    char third2 = check_word.charAt(2);
    String third22 = String.valueOf(third2);
    char fourth2 = check_word.charAt(3);
    String fourth22 = String.valueOf(fourth2);
    char fifth2 = check_word.charAt(4);
    String fifth22 = String.valueOf(fifth2);

    if (take_word.length()<7) {
        if (first1.trim().equals(first22)) {
            word_1.setText(first1);
            word_1.setForeground(Color.red);

        } else {
            count++;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Char 1 doesnt match");
            continue;
        }

        if (second1.trim().equals(second22)) {

            word_2.setText(second1);
            word_2.setForeground(Color.red);

        } else {
            count++;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Char 2 doesnt match");
            continue;
        }
        if (third1.trim().equals(third22)) {

            word_3.setText(third1);
            word_3.setForeground(Color.red);

        } else {
            count++;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Char 3 doesnt match");
            continue;
        }

        if (fourth1.trim().equals(fourth22)) {

            word_4.setText(fourth1);
            word_4.setForeground(Color.red);

        } else {

            count++;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Char 4 doesnt match");
            continue;
        }
        if (fifth1.trim().equals(fifth22)) {

            word_5.setText(fifth1);
            word_5.setForeground(Color.red);
            //displaying charchter on GUI
            break;
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "doesnt 5 match");
            count++;
            continue;
        }

    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "only 5 char word are allowed Number");
    }

    if (check_word.trim().equals(take_word)) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "YOU guessed the number in first attempt");
        break;
    } else {
        count++;
    }

  }

  System.out.println(count);
} catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println(e);
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: learn about java naming conventions. You dont use "_" in variable/method names (only for SOME_CONSTANT)

Comment: *I tried to break loop, but its not letting me input from label and just keep the previous entry from user and matches it again and again.* Question for you: why do you *want* to break from the loop - what is your objective? Another question: what does `continue` mean? The final question (which follows from the previous one): what is the first thing of significance that is going to occur when `continue` does its thing?

Comment: I figured it out myself actually there is no need for loop